# Android beginners

Tags: android

My android project shows error on the root folder(red cross on the application root folder)although any class or resource file inside the root folder does not show any error.

Comment: You might want to rename this question to match the description a bit better. This is a problem I've had in the past and it will be easier for people to find the solution with a better question title.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before and there have been a couple of different things that you can do to try and resolve it.

1. Right click on your project in the Package Explorer and go Source > Clean Up...
2. In the 'gen' directory find the R.java file and delete it. Then open up one of your project's XML files (could be layout, values, it doesn't matter), make a quick change and then save it. This will rebuild R.java to the state it was in before you deleted it, hopefully getting rid of your error.

Comment: I am curious why nobody gave the most important tip: Open the "Problems" view in eclipse and find out what the reason is. Without knowing the cause of the problem, every solution is just a trial and error...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project. Go to the *Project -> Clean..* on the toolbar. If you really don't have any errors, then that should fix the project.

Answer (score 0):

First Clean the project if this don't work then try Right Click on the project go to Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties, This should work if there is no errors actually in your project.